# How can you possibly stop a person who can reload life?

Tags: time-travel, super-powers

A random human, Bo, can reload life; whenever he dies, he simply loads back to before he was dead; whenever we catch him, he loads to before we catch him. Bo has been causing some problems and we need him to not be around, either by permanently killing him or preventing him from being able to reload.

As requested, here are the limits of his power

1. When he reloads, he reloads as far back as he wants within the last year
2. When he dies, he automatically reloads to the last week, where he can the reload further
3. He can only reload once a day (barring death reloads)

Assuming an unlimited budget, is there any way to stop Bo?

Comment: Does he only "reload" upon death? If so, we simply capture him, chain him up, and drop him into a convenient concrete hole with a feeding tube and a waste chute where he can reside forever and stop being a problem.

Comment: @JBiggs The question mentions that he "reloads" when caught.

Comment: yeah I re read and deleted my comment haha

Comment: If you can explain how he reloads and if there is a way to permenantly kill him you can find a more suitable answer to the question

Comment: Te be honest, this sounds like a terrible way to live. If he always "reloads" to before he died, then he'll be trapped in the last few seconds of his life. Unless he can control when he "reloads"... What about dying from old age?

Comment: @Frostfyre good point, I'll edit to clarify

Comment: oh god, stop that

Comment: How many saves does he have? You just have to convince him to save at a point where his downfall is already fait accompli.

Comment: @SRM he autosaves, the only limit is one load a day (and a load if he dies, regardless of amount)

Comment: I seriously doubt the combat tag belongs here. Reality check is also a mis-tag, as you're not asking for any reality check. Time Travel might be better here, since his "reloading" is essentially time travel

Comment: @Aify fixing the tags now

Comment: @TrEs-2b keep him asleep... When he falls asleep on his own you can start giving him sleeping substances so that he is always not captured (in his own house he's free) but never able to interfere

Comment: When you say "he can only reload once a day" does that mean 24 hours of his perception or once per calendar say? Aka, if it's Friday, can he reload to Thursday and then immediately to Wednesday? If it's Friday and he reloads to Thursday, will he be able to reload when it's Friday again?

Comment: If he rewinds back 1 year, and then tries to rewind back another year, is the result equivalent to going back 2 years?

Comment: And does Bo keep his memory when he rewinds?

Comment: @CortAmmon yes and yes

Comment: When do we become aware of him?  Do we know, at birth who he is and where he is?

Comment: Man, so many little details that have to be addressed when exploring ultra-overpowered superpowers.  You should probably fix the consistency issue in your question "... either by permanently killing him or preventing him from reloading somehow" is immediately followed by "We know of no way (and there is no way) to prevent him from reloading"

Comment: since he can reload father back than a year just by doing serial reloads you should mention that in the OP since it is fairly important. Also since the mechanism of reload is not described asking us to determine how to prevent reloading is pointless.

Comment: Edge of Tomorrow (2014) has a similar concept. IDK if it'll help you at all, but it's a fun watch nonetheless.

Comment: Also, is anyone else aware of the reloaded time? If not, then how do we know that we need to plan for it?

Comment: I think that an answer must make too many assumptions about how reloading works in order to produce an answer, making this question 'too broad.'

Comment: Many questions asking for specifics (can the peroson reload back a year, then immediately load back another year?  What does "once a day" mean when you can time travel by reloading?  etc) have been ignored.

Comment: the more I try to answer this, the more questions I'm starting to ask. I agree, this is too broad to answer without more details. You're asking about an absurdly powerful ability with a defense mechanism, but have condensed it all into a few bullet points, with two making it even stronger and one providing a vague limitation. A lot of clarifications need to be made.

Comment: Does "past year" extend backwards when he jumps backwards?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like all stories which involve creating an unstopable force and then beg for a way to stop it, the solution is to take the details and abuse the heck out of them.

His power to reverse time a year is powerful, but it's conscious.  That means it has a weakness.  His power to reverse time a week upon death is far *far* more powerful because it's triggered by some metaphysical "death" event.

The solution is to find a way to knock him unconscious (take your pick), and then immediately sedate him.  Put him in a medically induced coma for at least one week.  Then kill him.  This will trigger a rollback of one week, but he will be unconscious at that reload point, so he will not be able to enact a conscious reload.  He will not be "dead" at that point, so this will not automatically trigger the 1 week rollback from that point.  He'll just remain in a coma for 7 days again, and then get killed.

Now the real question is what happens to the rest of the universe when this one person who can magically "roll back" get stuck in a death loop like this.  Does the universe keep going?  Hopefully the answer is yes because otherwise the universe is 100% screwed... he's going to die eventually, of old age if nothing else.

Answer (score 7):

Control his information.

If his reloading is conscious (he decides to do it) then you can try to control his information. With an unlimited budget, you basically create an environment for him that works like the Truman Show: a potempkin village where the people around him are actors, his phone and computer are 100% hacked and displaying information you want him to have, and wherever he goes, he sees what you want him to see or is prevented from going there (not captured: prevented).

If his reloading is unconscious, you may have more options. You experiment with him until you know what constitutes "capture" and then you herd him to a place or locale where he isn't technically "captured" -there was no real "moment of capture" because he was traveling -something like the bottom of the Grand Canyon. You seal the exits and leave him be. You might experiment with this reloading as it applies to speed of death. In other words: if he starves to death over the course of several weeks, does it reload to before those weeks? If so, you can just throw him enough food to keep him alive but neutralized.

If none of the above works, you have to analyze HOW he is causing you trouble and deal with that. If he is causing trouble because he gets information out, you block his ability to do that, but otherwise leave him unharmed and un-captured. If he is planting bombs, you follow him constantly and diffuse the bombs, but leave him alone, prevent him from buying materials, etc. You follow him constantly, tail him everywhere he goes, and just stop him from doing specific things in ways that do NOT trigger a "reload".

Comment: This does not work.  No matter how you control him and how much food you "throw" at him, he will eventually die and reset.  In some reload he will eventually figure out that you have trapped him, and your jig is up - he will reset back year by year until he is out of your trap.  Even if he does not remember, in an eventual iteration a reload will happen within the first year of your Truman or Grand Canyon scenario.

Answer (score 6):

Fry his brain before he knows it, but without killing him.  Set up a trap to microwave part of his brain or give him a lobotomy.  Just enough to not kill him but turn him into a mindless person who does not know that he needs to reload.  And then put him in stasis.

The question is, when he dies, does his disembodied mind initiate the reload, or is it an automatic thing?  If it is automatic, forget it.  He will eventually die and you have no chance of stopping him.  If his disembodied mind initiates the reload, but that disembodied mind resets to full mental health at death, again, he will eventually die and you cannot stop him...  But with the 1 year time limit you added, hope is reborn.  You turn him into a mindless idiot and hold off his death for a year.  No matter if he dies, the best he can do is return to being a mindless idiot waiting to die.

If the reload is initiated by his disembodied mind, and that mind remains what it was at death, then you lobotomize the guy and kill him.  His after-death mind remains an idiot and does not realize that he needs to reload.

Comment: You are assuming the "reload" is consciously done and not an automatic function. If it wasn't conscious, this could be considered "capture".

Comment: I am not assuming anything of the sort.  I specifically address the case where the reload is automatic.  See paragraph 2.

Comment: No, because you mention stasis, but that is the same as "capture". Controlling his information is a better option than trying to lobotomize him.

Comment: You really think that a "Truman Show" kind of thing is a more practical and viable way to control someone's information than a lobotomy?  And stasis is not capture if the lobotomized reloader goes into it willingly (he is lobotomized and knows no better).

Comment: With the one year time limit the OP added, the stasis is not needed.  Just keep him alive for a year after the lobotomy.  The best the reloader can hope for, even if the reload after death is automatic, is to relive the last year of his mindless existence, over and over again.  If he is truly evil, that could be a poetic justice kind of thing - worst hell for me would be to be somewhat aware but mindless for eternity.

Answer (score 5):

**Plan A:** set up a failsafe plan that ensures his death at least one year before he actually dies.

If the circumstances are such that even if he reloads one entire year his death is still ensured, he will die. Such a situation could be a virus, a toxin, a disease, an assassination plan with enough contingencies that he can't do anything about it.

**Plan B:** depending on the technology available and depending on the specifics of how he can use his power. Put him to sleep, into a comma, under hypnosis or in a dream or give him brain damage. That way he's effectively out of the game but won't be able to do anything about it because he is either unconscious, dreaming or unable to even decide to go back.

**Plan C:** I don't know if this is even possible but guide him into a depression so bad that even if he dies, he won't want to reload.

Comment: Plan C is so freaking sad.

Comment: Yeah, I felt bad just thinking about it.

Comment: Wow, I thought my lobotomy idea, which is a form of your B option, was the only way.  But your plan C is plausible and just insidiously nasty - the sort of thing that could make for a great story.  If you can hold the depression for a year, he'd automatically reload back a week, and then relive the last week of his depressed life, over and over again.  This is the exact opposite of @Will 's answer - ingenious evil; +1.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what sort of world you're setting this in, so here are some possible solutions:

- **Matrix-like solution**: Give him a prison that creates the illusion of winning, when it's binding him utterly. Never thinks to escape.
- **HPMOR-like solution**: Total amnesia that makes him forget he has those powers. (Also, turn him into a <strike>newt</strike> pebble).
- **Star Trek/Stargate-like solution**: Stasis device to freeze him in time.
- **Comic book-like solution**: Another being with at least as much power who curb-stomps him.

One more thing… **paradox**: What happens if he gets an illness, perhaps cancer, that becomes certain to kill him a year before it becomes symptomatic?

Comment: is that happened, he would go back a year, wait a day then go back another year, etc until he was free of the disease

Comment: if that's the case, why is there even a one year limit when there's clearly nothing stopping him from going back further?

Comment: The only way to stop him is to take his mental abilities away, so that he is either unaware that he needs to reload, unaware that he is able, or both.  Then, as long as he dies more than a year after the loss of his mental abilities, and even if he reloads automatically, the best he can hope for is to relive his last year of a mindless existence, over and over.

Answer (score 3):

Kill him so many times that he *automatically* reloads to before his conception. Find a way to embed some sort of information into him that travels back with him, like a phrase or something similar, that automatically causes everyone around him to try to kill him.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't beat him, co-opt him.  Persuade him to stay in the present.  He has to have a reason: love, family, achievements - something that he would give up by going back and doing over.  Maybe he did have something like that in a different timeline and when his back was against the wall he had to give it up with a series of jumpbacks.  Once he jumps back in the timeline to before it happens it probably will not happen again.   Now he is bitter and bitter demigods are trouble.  Talk to him and understand what it was that he lost and how with help he might be able to get it back.

The extreme take on this is a present so good he will not want to leave. He reloads a groundhog-day like repeat of the perfect day, over and over, forever.  He causes no more trouble.  I think Heaven might be like this.

What a great ending to the story that would be.

Comment: You, sir, are a positive guy.  And while I am also very positive, this answer manages to think in a way that is very different from my own.  I really like that.  +1.

Answer (score 2):

The only plausible solution to this problem per the constraints you have set is to use a super fast acting coma inducing drug.

Even that is not a guarantee though, reloading on capture is not the problem.  In that case he is making a mental choice to reset.  But if he can also cause a reset on his death that would appear to be a failsafe, like a dead man's switch on heavy equipment.

If he can do that without mentally choosing to do so I don't know that there is any way to stop him at all.

My best suggestion is to drug him and keep him in an induced coma so that he cannot die, but also cannot mentally choose to reset.

Comment: You are assuming the "reload" is a conscious choice and not automatic.

Comment: @JBiggs - no, he is not.  He explicitly speaks about whether the reset is conscious or not - "**if** he can do that without mentally choosing."  You are just trying to knock other people's answers.